Como llenar una ComboBox con una tabla de SQLite
estoy tratando de llenar un Combo Box con datos de una tabla de sqlite, ya realice un método para ello, solo que al momento de ejecutar y abrir mi Combo Box no me aparece nada, quisiera que me ayudaran diciéndome que corrijo en mi método si está mal.
MÉTODO
public void getValues(JComboBox boxCientifico) {
    ResultSet rs ;
        PreparedStatement ps ;
        Conexion con = new Conexion();
    try {
        ps = con.conectar().prepareStatement("SELECT NombreCientifico FROM EspeciePlanta");
        
        
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
       boxCientifico.addItem("Selecciona una opción");
        
        while (rs.next()) {
            boxCientifico.addItem(rs.getString("NombreCientifico"));
            
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    

   
}

}
MANDO A LLAMAR AL MÉTODO EN MI FRAME
public Cultivo() {
    initComponents();

    comboBox cb = new comboBox() ;
   cb.getValues(boxNombres);
}


Como mandas llamar Cultivo?

Cultivo es el nombre de mi JInternal Frame, estoy creando un objeto para la clase comboBox, y mando a llamar al metod getValues en el constructor de mi JInternal Frame, que contiene la consulta a mi base de datos
